# Why doesn't Cosmos DB multiple write regions guarantee write availability during a region outage?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, high-availability

Cosmos DB documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability#what-to-expect-during-a-cosmos-db-region-outage) says that "Given the internal Azure Cosmos DB architecture, using multiple write regions doesn't guarantee write availability during a region outage. The best configuration to achieve high availability during a region outage is single write region with service-managed failover."

Does that mean multi-region writes is just for distributing workloads with limited availability? What is the internal Azure Cosmos DB architecture and where can I get it?

In my understanding, if there is an outage in one region, all writes from that region should be re-directed to other region writes and seamlessly update the database. Is it correct?

Comment: great question, I'm after this answer as well